# Не ловится сигнал после старта процесса

Tags: c++, qt

Не могу понять, почему не ловится сигнал после старта gdb:

1. Процесс не посылает?
2. Слот не видит?
3. Неправильно организован connect?

Прошу подсказать, буду очень признателен :)

Код:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QObject>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

class gdbInterface : public QObject {

     Q_OBJECT
public:
     QProcess gdb;
     QString gdbProgram;
     QStringList gdbArguments;
     qint64 pid;
public slots:
    void onGDBConnected(){
        qDebug() << "Pirate!";
    }

public:
    gdbInterface(){
        gdbArguments << "-q"
                      << "/home/byeti/project/meerkat/meerkat_src/rat_lab"
                      ;//<< "--interpreter=mi";

        gdb.setProgram("gdb");
        gdb.setArguments(gdbArguments);
        connect(&gdb, &QProcess::started, this , &gdbInterface::onGDBConnected);
    }
};

#include "main.moc"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    gdbInterface interface;
    interface.gdb.startDetached(&interface.pid);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак. Вопрос решён.

`startDetached` создаёт свою сессию, в этом дело. Надо было запустить через `start();`

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `getchar()`.
В Вашем случае не доходило до запуска цикла обработки событий Qt

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    gdbInterface interface;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает :(